# python accessing class variables in instances from derived classes

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have gone through many answers and not found what I understand to be the answer.  This is a test program based on a problem in my real program.  I want to have a class variable that I can change and have the change apply to all instances of a class, but not to a similar class even with the same form.

As is probably obvious, I am defining a class variable for X in line 3 and a class variable for Y in line 9.  I am trying to access these in lines 23-25.

My model is

```
 #! /usr/bin/python -t
 class X:
      clsvar = "Animal"
      def show(self):
          clsvar
      def chg(self,creature):
          clsvar  = creature
 class Y:
      clsvar = "Plant"
      def show(self):
          clsvar
      def chg(self,creature):
          clsvar  = creature
 class A(X):
      pass
 class B(X):
      pass
 class C(Y):
      pass
 a = A()
 b = B()
 c = C()
 print "1 " + a.show()
 print "2 " + b.show()
 print "3 " + c.show()
 a.chg( "Dog")
 print "4 " + a.show()
 print "5 " + b.show()
 print "6 " + c.show()
```

My result is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "180.py", line 23, in ?
    print "1 " + a.show()
  File "180.py", line 5, in show
    clsvar
NameError: global name 'clsvar' is not defined
```

I would have thought clsvar would appear in any of the derived classes and not need to be global.  I am obviously being stupid here but I have tried this dozens of ways without success.

Incidentally, I was able to do this in Ruby.

```
 #! /usr/bin/ruby -w
 class X
      @@clsvar = "Animal"
      def self.show
          @@clsvar
      end
      def self.chg(creature)
          @@clsvar  = creature
      end
 end
 class Y
      @@clsvar = "Plant"
      def self.show
          @@clsvar
      end
      def self.chg(creature)
          @@clsvar  = creature
      end
 end
 class A < X
      A.show
 end
 class B < X
      B.show
 end
 class C < Y
      C.show
 end
 a = A
 b = B
 c = C
 puts "1 " + a.show 
 puts "2 " + b.show 
 puts "3 " + c.show 
 a.chg( "Dog")
 puts "4 " + a.show 
 puts "5 " + b.show 
 puts "6 " + c.show
```

And the output is:

```
1 Animal

2 Animal

3 Plant

4 Dog

5 Dog

6 Plant
```

Answer (score 2):

To access a class variable you have to do this:

```
MyClass.clsvar
```

Or even this:

```
an_instance.clsvar
```

The latter works only if the instance does not have any instance variable called `clsvar`.(*)

Python is not like Java. Take into account that, unlike Java, Python *does* have global variables. For example:

```
a = 1
class MyClass:
    a = 2
    def show(self):
        print(a)
```

The `show` method would print `1`, since it refers to the global variable `a`, and not to `MyClass.a`.

---

(*) A note on this. You can access `MyClass.var` using `self.var` and it's fine if you do not modify it. But setting the value is **not** equivalent. If you want to set a class variable then you have to use `MyClass.var = value` and not `an_instance.var = value`. The latter would create a new instance variable called `var` with value `value`, so `MyClass.var` will still have the old value.

---

By the way, I do not know Ruby, but I think the `@@` syntax is used to access class variables so that's why it works.

Finally, your code is incorrect. You probably want to put some `return` statements in those methods, otherwise you'll get some `TypeError`s when executing it.